# Are there any JSS deploy events to which I can tap my custom code?

Tags: sitecore-client, jss, sitecore-api, sitecore-install-framework

Just looking if there are any events that are triggered while doing jss deploy?Similar to the other events 
item:copied
packageinstall:ended ...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a config which contains events executed during deploy. Search for Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.config under ".\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices" folder.

This file contains "import", "create.item", "update.item" etc. Based on your requirement you can patch respective pipeline.

```
<import>
   <processor type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.Pipelines.Import.EnableSecurity, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices" />
    ...
</import>
<create.item>
    ...
</create.item>
<update.item>
    ...
</update.item>
<import.field>
    ...
</import.field>
<create.media>
    ...
</create.media>
<import.layout>
    ...
</import.layout>
<create.renderingInstance>
    ...
</create.renderingInstance>
```